# Is there any GUI application that runs on both Mac OS X 10.0 Cheetah and macOS 10.13.4 High Sierra?

Tags: high-sierra, compatibility, macos

I'm trying to make the argument that macOS (Mac OS X) has a very long legacy as a desktop operating system, but my colleagues brought up the point that it's gone through so many iterations since 10.0 that it might as well be considered completely different.

My question is this: **Is there any way to run even one GUI application on both Cheetah and High Sierra?**

Dirty tricks can be used, but it has to be the same distributable (e.g. `.app` file). I don't really care if it's a fat binary, or if I have to install a different window server or anything like that. As long as I can somehow demonstrate to my colleagues that I have a GUI application that I can run on Cheetah that also runs just fine on High Sierra.

Comment: This might get to be a bit of a list, but maybe someone can eventually find something old enough. Oldest app I can find is UnRarX, from 2006. Still working [though now with the 32-bit warning] Finding the oldest app needs a machine old enough to still have the created datestamp. I had to look at an 08 Mac Pro to find that one. My first OSX-capable machine went to the great recycler in the sky a long time ago.

Comment: You could try [Firefox 1.5.0.2](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/1.5.0.2/mac/en-US/Firefox%201.5.0.2.dmg) which still technically runs today. I don't know if it would work on Cheetah.

Comment: Gosh! Interesting question. If I get a chance on the weekend I'll boot up an old PowerMac G4 that still has Cheetah installed on one of its internal drives and see if I can get any of the apps to run on my iMac Pro. It'll be fun! LOL **But**, there is the other factor to consider in your quest/argument and that is the move from PowerPC to Intel.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Firefox 1.5.0.2 won't work according to [release notes](https://website-archive.mozilla.org/www.mozilla.org/firefox_releasenotes/en-US/firefox/releases/1.5.0.11.html): "Starting with Firefox 1.5, Mac OS X PowerPC users must have Mac OS X 10.2 or greater."

Comment: I don't know if requiring things to run back on 10.0 is really relevant. 10.0 was really more of a second beta release than a usable OS; it just wasn't ready for real use. In fact, while the next few versions got better fact, I'd consider 10.4 (or maaaaybe 10.3) the first version that I'd have considered fully usable.

Comment: I agree with @GordonDavisson - I glanced at each version up to 10.4; & that was when I switched over.

Comment: The fast rate of API depreciation, PPC/Intel switch followed so radically by Apple and most developers make this unlikely for any stock application. Such an app has to be specially crafted. Your colleagues are just right on this one. Find an Apple binary from 10.0 that still runs, that would be a litmus test to win fairly.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_10.0), Cheetah was shipped with AppleScript. So if you can have a Mac running Snow Leopard, according to comments of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10540995/8108843) (and not the answer, it's strange), it seems that an AppleScript saved as app give a universal app (PowerPC G4 and above, or Intel). I haven't tested, but perhaps if you save this AppleScript:

```
display dialog "hello"
```

as app on the Snow Leopard's AppleScript Editor, it will run under Cheetah and High Sierra.

This AppleScript app is very simple, and display "hello" in a window, with a "OK" button. So this is a very simple GUI application.

Comment: +1 Haha, I was thinking about doing something like this on the weekend just to see what happens (although with an interactive AppleScript app that uses windows/dialog boxes). Will be interesting to see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Most Java applets?

Could wrap it in an .app container with a shell script that launches the java and loads the applet.

Comment: While true, that won't really prove my point to my colleagues since the same applet will run on Windows and Linux :)

Comment: @BenLeggiero Did your colleagues say it couldn't? =D I might try investigating universal binaries in this case. Something simple built with PPC + 32bit intel has a chance to do this, ignoring other dependencies.

Comment: If you are really up for experimenting: Chess.app is opensource and available from Apple from v45 – v322. You might build both (the first on 10.0 machine – so old ProjectBuilder files do not offer a straght pugrade path…) then lipo them together ((how) does 10.0 handle fat-binaries?)? That would be quite a cool hack, even if in-between OS versions have some trouble and only slightly cheating. ;)